# Android getStringExtra and Update record

Tags: android, sqlite

I get a string stored in the db to change it. I'm stuck in the method db.update because I have to change all the strings that match the value received. for example I have 15 records in field1 with the string "sun" and change it to "sun1" need to be changed all the correspondents.

I tried that but it does not work

```
cv.put(MyTable.FIELD1, Ec.getText().toString());
        String cat_modificare = (i.getStringExtra("value"));
            db.update(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, cv, cat_modificare + "=" + MyTable.FIELD1, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write something into the `whereClause`, it is interpreted as a column name unless you format it correctly.

String values should always be used as parameters:

```java
db.update(MyTable.TABLE_NAME, cv,
          MyTable.FIELD1 + " = ?",
          new String[] { cat_modificare });
```